# sort all rows from a table with pagination

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, object

i'm building a table with pagination and sorting functionality and i'm missing something on sorting the items from all the pages.

1. what i want to do is to sort all items from page 1 and page 2 and not only from the current page that i'm on. can you please tell me how should i update my code to achieve that?
2. and i'm having another issue with the last column. how can i create a link with the href from propURL? at this moment i'm getting [object Object]

here i have a fiddle with my code

https://jsfiddle.net/c2kmruLs/2/

```
 <div class="book-component">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
    </div>
  </div>

var data =  {
    "headings": [
      {
        "displayName": "Book",
        "columnID": "bookID"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "Author",
        "columnID": "authorID"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "Year",
        "columnID": "yearID"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "",
        "columnID": "urlID"
      }
    ],
    "items": [
      {
        "bookID": "The Great Gatsby",
        "authorID": " F Scott Fitzgerald",
        "yearID": "1925",
        "urlId": {
          "name": "View book",
          "propURL": "https://google.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "bookID": "The Grapes of Wrath",
        "authorID": "John Steinbeck",
        "yearID": "1939",
        "urlId": {
          "name": "View book",
          "propURL": "https://google.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "bookID": "A Wild Sheep Chase",
        "authorID": "Haruki Murakami",
        "yearID": "1982",
        "urlId": {
          "name": "View book",
          "propURL": "https://google.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "bookID": "A Farewell to Arms",
        "authorID": "Ernest Hemingway",
        "yearID": "1929",
       "urlId": {
          "name": "View book",
          "propURL": "https://google.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  
  
var TABLE = document.createElement('table');
TABLE.setAttribute('class', 'pagination');
TABLE.setAttribute('data-pagecount', '2');
const TABLE_WRAPPER = document.querySelector('.book-component .table-wrapper');
  TABLE_WRAPPER.appendChild(TABLE);


for (const field in data) {
      var tr = document.createElement('tr'); 
   if(field == "headings"){

      for (const child in data.headings) {
         var th = document.createElement('th');
           th.setAttribute('class', 'sort-cta');
         tr.appendChild(th);
         th.innerText = data.headings[child].displayName; 
         TABLE.appendChild(tr);
       }
   }
   else if(field == "items"){
      for (const child in data.items) {
         var tr = document.createElement('tr'); 
         let item = data.items[child];
         for (const row in item) {
          var td = document.createElement('td');
          tr.appendChild(td);
          td.innerText = item[row]; 
          TABLE.appendChild(tr);
         }
       }
   }
}

const SORT_LINK = document.querySelectorAll('.sort-cta');
  SORT_LINK.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
      sortTable(0);
    });
  });

function sortTable(n) {
  var table,
    rows,
    switching,
    i,
    x,
    y,
    shouldSwitch,
    dir,
    switchcount = 0;
  table = document.querySelector('.pagination');
  switching = true;
  dir = 'asc';
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    for (i = 1; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('TD')[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName('TD')[n];
      if (dir == 'asc') {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == 'desc') {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      switchcount++;
    } else {
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == 'asc') {
        dir = 'desc';
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}


var perPage = 20;

function genTables() {
    var tables = document.querySelectorAll(".pagination");
    for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        perPage = parseInt(tables[i].dataset.pagecount);
        createFooters(tables[i]);
        createTableMeta(tables[i]);
        loadTable(tables[i]);
    }
}


function loadTable(table) {
    var startIndex = 0;

    if (table.querySelector('th'))
        startIndex = 1;



    var start = (parseInt(table.dataset.currentpage) * table.dataset.pagecount) + startIndex;
    var end = start + parseInt(table.dataset.pagecount);
    var rows = table.rows;

    for (var x = startIndex; x < rows.length; x++) {
        if (x < start || x >= end)
            rows[x].classList.add("inactive");
        else
            rows[x].classList.remove("inactive");
    }
}

function createTableMeta(table) {
    table.dataset.currentpage = "0";
}

function createFooters(table) {
    var hasHeader = false;
    if (table.querySelector('th'))
        hasHeader = true;

    var rows = table.rows.length;

    if (hasHeader)
        rows = rows - 1;

    var numPages = rows / perPage;
    var pager = document.createElement("div");

    
    if (numPages % 1 > 0)
        numPages = Math.floor(numPages) + 1;

    pager.className = "pager";
    for (var i = 0; i < numPages ; i++) {
        var page = document.createElement("div");
        page.innerHTML = i + 1;
        page.className = "pager-item";
        page.dataset.index = i;

        if (i == 0)
            page.classList.add("selected");

        page.addEventListener('click', function() {
            var parent = this.parentNode;
            var items = parent.querySelectorAll(".pager-item");
            for (var x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
                items[x].classList.remove("selected");
            }
            this.classList.add('selected');
            table.dataset.currentpage = this.dataset.index;
            loadTable(table);
        });
        pager.appendChild(page);
    }

    
    table.parentNode.insertBefore(pager, table);
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    genTables();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question: I'm not sure if that is very useful for the user, because if you sort your second page of the table you will always have the highest value in your first page of your table. And that is something you won't do I guess.

Second question: You see an [obejct object], because you want to show that object directly. You have to loop again to show the value for it.

```
for (const row in item) {
          var td = document.createElement('td');
          
          if (typeof(item[row]) === 'object') {

              for (const obj in item[row]) {
           
                  tr.appendChild(td);
                  td.innerHTML = '<a target="_blank" href="' + item[row][obj] + '">' + item[row][obj] + '</a>'; 
                  TABLE.appendChild(tr);
                  TABLE.appendChild(tr);
              }
                  
          } else {
                  tr.appendChild(td);
                  td.innerText = item[row]; 
                  TABLE.appendChild(tr);
          }
  }
```

See example below:

```js
var data =  {
    "headings": [
      {
        "displayName": "Book",
        "columnID": "bookID"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "Author",
        "columnID": "authorID"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "Year",
        "columnID": "yearID"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "",
        "columnID": "urlID"
      }
    ],
    "items": [
      {
        "bookID": "The Great Gatsby",
        "authorID": " F Scott Fitzgerald",
        "yearID": "1925",
        "urlId": {
          "name": "View book",
          "propURL": "https://google.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "bookID": "The Grapes of Wrath",
        "authorID": "John Steinbeck",
        "yearID": "1939",
        "urlId": {
          "name": "View book",
          "propURL": "https://google.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "bookID": "A Wild Sheep Chase",
        "authorID": "Haruki Murakami",
        "yearID": "1982",
        "urlId": {
          "name": "View book",
          "propURL": "https://google.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "bookID": "A Farewell to Arms",
        "authorID": "Ernest Hemingway",
        "yearID": "1929",
       "urlId": {
          "name": "View book",
          "propURL": "https://google.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  
  
var TABLE = document.createElement('table');
TABLE.setAttribute('class', 'pagination');
TABLE.setAttribute('data-pagecount', '2');
const TABLE_WRAPPER = document.querySelector('.book-component .table-wrapper');
  TABLE_WRAPPER.appendChild(TABLE);


for (const field in data) {
      var tr = document.createElement('tr'); 
   if(field == "headings"){

      for (const child in data.headings) {
         var th = document.createElement('th');
           th.setAttribute('class', 'sort-cta');
         tr.appendChild(th);
         th.innerText = data.headings[child].displayName; 
         TABLE.appendChild(tr);
       }
   }
   else if(field == "items"){
      for (const child in data.items) {
         var tr = document.createElement('tr'); 
         let item = data.items[child];
         for (const row in item) {
          var td = document.createElement('td');
          
          if (typeof(item[row]) === 'object') {
          for (const obj in item[row]) {
           
           tr.appendChild(td);

             td.innerHTML = '<a target="_blank" href="' + item[row][obj] + '">' + item[row][obj] + '</a>'; 
             TABLE.appendChild(tr);
          }
                  
          } else {
                    tr.appendChild(td);

             td.innerText = item[row]; 
             TABLE.appendChild(tr);
          }
         }
       }
   }
}

const SORT_LINK = document.querySelectorAll('.sort-cta');
  SORT_LINK.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
      sortTable(0);
    });
  });

function sortTable(n) {
  var table,
    rows,
    switching,
    i,
    x,
    y,
    shouldSwitch,
    dir,
    switchcount = 0;
  table = document.querySelector('.pagination');
  switching = true;
  dir = 'asc';
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
        
    for (i = 1; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('TD')[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName('TD')[n];
      if (dir == 'asc') {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == 'desc') {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      switchcount++;
    } else {
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == 'asc') {
        dir = 'desc';
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}


var perPage = 20;

function genTables() {
    var tables = document.querySelectorAll(".pagination");
    for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        perPage = parseInt(tables[i].dataset.pagecount);
        createFooters(tables[i]);
        createTableMeta(tables[i]);
        loadTable(tables[i]);
    }
}

// based on current page, only show the elements in that range
function loadTable(table) {
    var startIndex = 0;

    if (table.querySelector('th'))
        startIndex = 1;

    var start = (parseInt(table.dataset.currentpage) * table.dataset.pagecount) + startIndex;
    var end = start + parseInt(table.dataset.pagecount);
    var rows = table.rows;

    for (var x = startIndex; x < rows.length; x++) {
        if (x < start || x >= end)
            rows[x].classList.add("inactive");
        else
            rows[x].classList.remove("inactive");
    }
}

function createTableMeta(table) {
    table.dataset.currentpage = "0";
}

function createFooters(table) {
    var hasHeader = false;
    if (table.querySelector('th'))
        hasHeader = true;

    var rows = table.rows.length;

    if (hasHeader)
        rows = rows - 1;

    var numPages = rows / perPage;
    var pager = document.createElement("div");

    // add an extra page, if we're 
    if (numPages % 1 > 0)
        numPages = Math.floor(numPages) + 1;

    pager.className = "pager";
    for (var i = 0; i < numPages ; i++) {
        var page = document.createElement("div");
        page.innerHTML = i + 1;
        page.className = "pager-item";
        page.dataset.index = i;

        if (i == 0)
            page.classList.add("selected");

        page.addEventListener('click', function() {
            var parent = this.parentNode;
            var items = parent.querySelectorAll(".pager-item");
            for (var x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
                items[x].classList.remove("selected");
            }
            this.classList.add('selected');
            table.dataset.currentpage = this.dataset.index;
            loadTable(table);
        });
        pager.appendChild(page);
    }

    // insert page at the top of the table
    table.parentNode.insertBefore(pager, table);
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    genTables();
});
```

```css
tr.inactive {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .table-wrapper {
      display: flex;
flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
.pager {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: 800;
}    
    
.pager-item.selected {
  outline: none;
    border-color: #0077cc;
    background: #0077cc;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-component">
    <div class="table-wrapper">

    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: makes perfect sense what you are saying regardin the first question. but for the second one, thanks for the time to answer, but i still don't get it how can i build a link with the href attribute to be the value from propUrl, and append the btn inside the td for that column and not to have it like string.

Comment: You are welcome. You can add a link if you change the `innerText` to `innerHTML` and add your link tag within. 
td.innerHTML = '<a target="_blank" href="' + item[row][obj] + '">' + item[row][obj] + '</a>';

Comment: and one last question :)) for the sorting part is there a way if the sorting is triggered from the second page to get back always to the first page and to have there the all the values sorted desc? and for the first page always toggle between the asc and desc value? if makes sense what i'm saying

Comment: This is possible, but not the best practice. Imagine the user always jumps from page to page when sorting the table.

In most cases, the users want to sort the data per page and are aware of this. I don't know how much data you want to display in the table, but lazy loading tables and searching with database query have always worked well.

When displaying tables there are also good frameworks that make your work easier.

https://bashooka.com/coding/javascript-data-table-libraries/

Comment: If you think my answer was useful, I would be happy if you could mark it as correct. :o)